# HTTP webservice no response

Tags: networking, tcp, wireshark, web-services

We have some issues on a connection between 2 devices through ASP webservices. On Wireshark, we saw that the request arrives to the destination computer and the IIS sends the response, but the origin computer does not receive the response.

If we restart both computers, it works but suddenly it stop working (it works about 5 hours, then it fails).

If we query to the webservice in localhost, it always work. And it also works on the other direction.

The remote computer answer to ping and telnet on port 8085 but webservice ASMX page doesn't load.

Please, find attached a wireshark screenshot:

[image: Wireshark not working]

Do you think it could be a network issue? Both computers are connected through a LAN by using many switchs. Also, both computers have Windows 10 Pro installed.

When it is working, this is the screenshot captured on wireshark:

[image: Wireshark working]

Please, any help would be really appreciated? We don't know what's causing the issue.

Thank you.

Comment: Check for firewalls between the two systems.

Comment: @MichaelHampton There is no firewall between both computers, only a plain switch. Also, when you restart the computer it works until it suddendly stops working. We think it could be due to a timeout or network traffic load.

Comment: A timeout would imply a FIN or a RST from the client to close the connection or refuse the outdated response. To block such a simple request from being received just by network load even though you had so many retransmissions, you'd need a LOT of traffic. Some security solutions have some kind of "security proxy" included which may be eating up the response and blocking it. Check if your security solution has this kind of protection.

Comment: Windows firewall and windows defender are disabled. No security solution is enabled at the moment. We notice that is something related to TCP protocol because FTP (to a Filezilla server) connects but when you execute a "ls" command, it aborts the connection. After restarting the computer, it works without any issues. We want to find what is happening to avoid restaring the computer. Thanks.

Comment: We have executed those commands: netsh interface set interface "Ethernet" disable and netsh interface set interface "Ethernet" enable and it starts working again without rebooting.